# Removing first forward slash from string

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I'm trying to remove the first / from a string in a shell script.

For example

> file:///path/to/file

and output to

> file://path/to/file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the string is in a shell variable, then you can use shell parameter expansion:

```
$ var='file:///path/to/file'

$ echo "${var/\//}"
file://path/to/file
```

Comment: IMHO this is the true answer, as it doesn't rely on calls to other programs to answer the OP's question.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

Something like will do the work:

```
A="file:///path/to/file"
B=$(echo $A|sed 's@/@@')
```

without `g` at the end in `sed` the program will change only first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

I Tried with below method and it worked fine

```
@praveen_linux_example ~]# echo "file:///path/to/file" | sed "s/\///1"
file://path/to/file

Command: echo "file:///path/to/file" | sed "s/\///1"
```

Output

```
file://path/to/file
```